# what's the difference between ServiceHost and WebServiceHost?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, c#-4.0

For .Net4, is there any difference between the following

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/test");
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), baseAddress);
host.Open();
```

and

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/test");
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(TestService), baseAddress);
host.Open();
```

all the books recommend using webServiceHost, but why I cannot see difference?

Answer (score 6):

The `WebServiceHost` class is based on the `ServiceHost` class.

It comes with `WebHttpBinding` and `WebHttpBehavior` by default. (The nice thing is you don't need a configuration file, for simple use.)

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx):

> When you use WebServiceHost instead of ServiceHost, it will automatically create a Web endpoint for you using the base HTTP address and configure the injected endpoint with the WebHttpBehavior

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebServiceHost(Object, Uri[])` constructor when you have the service type and you can create new instances of it when needed, even when you need a singleton instance. Use the `ServiceHost(Object, Uri[])` constructor instead only when you want the service host to use a specific singleton instance of the service.

Comment: you mean ServiceHost is singleton, but WebServiceHost is not? any proof?

Comment: @AdamLee read the remark from this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585489(v=vs.100).aspx) page